# How do I do a convolution in pytorch where the kernel is different for each minibatch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Let me express the title with an example:

Let A be a tensor of shape [16, **15**, 128, 128] (which means [batchsize, channels, height, width])

Let B be a tensor of shape [16,  **3**, 128, 128] (which means [batchsize, channels, height, width])

I want to output a tensor of shape [16, **5**, 128, 128] (which means [batchsize, channels, height, width])

Where the *i_th* channel of the 5 channels of the output is computed by 
multiplying elementwise B with the *i_th* slice of 3 channels of A and them performing a sum along the channel dimension.

How would you do that operation in pytorch?

Thanks!

PD: It's very difficult to express what I want from the operation, if I wasn't clear, please ask me and I'll try to reexplain it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.repeat_interleave) to help you "extend" `B` tensor to have 15 channels (5 groups of the 3 input channels):

```py
extB = torch.repeat_interleave(B, 3, dim=1)  # extend B to have 15 channels
m = A * extB  # element wise multiplication of A with the extended version of B
# using some reshaping and mean we can get the 5 output channels you want
out = m.view(m.shape[0], 5, 3, *m.shape[2:]).mean(dim=2)
```